# Encoding issue when setting up CRON as user?

Tags: ruby, csv, cron, watir, selenium-chromedriver

I've set up CRON to run a code that works fine when run directly from the terminal, but fires up errors when run via CRON.

I've appended the cron via

> env EDITOR=nano crontab -e

To run a Ruby code as if from the standard terminal user.
The code requires ruby (including 'watir' and 'csv' gems) and chromedriver.

```
58      10      *       *       *       PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; /Users/sybren/chromedriver;  Ruby 'ruby/mycode.rb'
```

The PATH is there to change (environment) settings to my local user settings.
The '/Users/sybren/chromedriver' is there to load chromedriver as an environment variable. At the end it runs my ruby code ('Ruby 'ruby/mycode.rb'')

It fires up the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1987:in `=~': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1987:in `init_separators'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1509:in `initialize'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1261:in `new'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1261:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1119:in `foreach'
```

There is no '~' in my ruby code. And again, the code runs fine when run from terminal. What is going wrong here? I believe it is giving the error when opening a new csv and iterating through it.

Comment: try to add `# encoding: UTF-8` in the very beginning of your file

Comment: @Aleksey in ruby 2.0.0 this is a default setting, adding it to _ruby_ files makes no sense.

Comment: @mudasobwa right, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code where you open and/or read the file content, [set the encoding](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-CSV+and+Character+Encodings+-28M17n+or+Multilingualization-29) for it explicitly:

```
CSV.open(filename, encoding: Encoding::UTF-8.name) ...
```

Comment: Solved, with `CSV.foreach("csvfile.csv", col_sep: ",", encoding: "iso8859-1:UTF-8") do |row|` It is throwing a new error (me and cron aren't good friends) but the encoding issue is fixed at least! Thanks